# PHP URL Routing; Variables to 'directory'

Tags: php, url, routes

Is it possible to **change**

`host/index.php?variable=3`

to

`host/index.php/3`

---

In my instance I'm using

`host/bot?id=3`

But I'd like it to be

`host/bot/3` <-- This will be the only variable EVER used

How can I accomplish this, any links or code you can provide?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe you'll find the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/16389034/1352271

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL rewriting with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GET    /hotels/:id            Hotels.Show

Segments of the path may be matched and extracted with a : prefix.
The :id variable above will match anything except a slash. For example, /hotels/123 and /hotels/abc would both be matched by the route above.
Extracted parameters are available in both the
Controller.Params map
and via Action method parameters.

https://revel.github.io/manual/routing.html

Comment: As far as I know, I don't use any